# Populate updated data into table after submitting the form in VueJS

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js

I have an endpoint to submit data using POST request,

http://localhost:3000/entry

Keys are fname, lname, age

I can make a POST request into the given end point and it will create an entry. It successfully submits the data. But, whenever I submit the form, it is redirecting to the endpoint (that is http://localhost:3000/entry) . I don't want to redirect the URL. I am using VueJS.

I have one more end point,

http://localhost:3000/entries (GET) , it returns all the existing entries in a JSON. Example,

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b48a137c3b2a3454b853a3c",
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Jose",
        "age": "28",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b506cc7d9105012f59c87e6",
        "fname": "Alex",
        "lname": "Cruz",
        "age": "27",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Instead of redirecting to the endpoint URL, I want to populate the updated data in the HTML table by calling the API http://localhost:3000/entries whenever I submit the form.

index.html :-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.16/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>
          Dashboard
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <form class="row" id="app" @submit="checkForm" action="http://localhost:3000/entry" method="post">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="fname" name="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="fname" name="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="environment">Age</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="age" name="age" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input href="#" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form> 

    <div>&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="row" v-if="debug">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Table Start -->

    <div class="row">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{fname}}</td>
          <td>{{lname}}</td>
          <td>{{age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Table END -->

  </div>
</div>
```

script.js :-

```
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    errors:[],
    fname:null,
    lname:null,
    age:null
  },
  methods:{
    checkForm:function(e) {
      if(this.fname) return true;
      this.errors = [];
      if(!this.fname) this.errors.push("First name required.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },

})
```

Updated Table :-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.16/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>
          Dashboard
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div> 


    <form class="row" @submit.prevent="checkForm">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="fname" name="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="lname" name="lname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="environment">Age</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="age" name="age" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input href="#" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit" :disabled="isSaving">
        <span v-show='isSaving'>Saving...</span>
      </div>
    </form> 

    <div>&nbsp;</div>



    <!-- Table Start -->

    <div class="row">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="item in objects" :key="item._id">
          <!-- item.fname -->
          <td>{{item.fname}}</td>
          <!-- item.lname -->
          <td>{{item.lname}}</td>
          <!-- item.age -->
          <td>{{item.age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Table END -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `checkForm` method returns before `e.preventDefault()` if you have typed anything in the fname-input. Move `e.preventDefault()` to the top of the method, and that should stop the form from navigating.

Also, your last name input also has `fname` as v-model.

To populate the table I'd use something like this:

index.html

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(row, index) in table" :key="index">
        <td>{{row.fname}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lname}}</td>
        <td>{{row.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

script.js

```
data: {
    return {
        ...
        table: []
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.populateTable()
},
methods: {
    checkForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.fname) {
            table.push({ fname: this.fname, lname: this.lname, age: this.age })
            return true;
        }
        this.errors = [];
        if (!this.fname) this.errors.push("First name required.");
        return false;
    },
    populateTable() {
        /* GET-request, put into this.table */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data to server with ajax request instead of form action:

1. In template `form` should open like this (without action and method):

   ```
   <form class="row" @submit.prevent="checkForm">
   ```
2. Use ajax to send data to server (I see you use **vue-resource**):

   ```
   checkForm:function(e) {
       this.errors = [];
       if(!this.fname) this.errors.push("First name required.");
       if (this.errors.length) {
          return;
       }
       var data = {
           fname: this.fname,
           lname: this.lname,
           age: this.age
       }
       this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/entry', data, { emulateJSON: true })
       .then(function(){
           console.log('Saved!');
        });
   }
   ```
3. So data in table automatically updates.

**UPDATE**

You need also array of objects to render table correctly, now I see.
I prepared example, but I changed url to jsonplaceholder to show that it works.
After saving form app fetches all objects from server (but you will not see new created object in my example because i use public API that is not allowed to change entire collection just allows making requests, when you add correct own URLs it will work). Also you need to change output fields in table to correct ones - I added comments.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    errors:[],
    fname:null,
    lname:null,
    age:null,
    isSaving: false,
    objects: []
  },
  created() {
      this.getAll();
  },
  methods:{
    checkForm:function(e) {
      this.errors = [];
      if(!this.fname) this.errors.push("First name required.");
      if (this.errors.length) {
         return;
      }
      this.isSaving = true;
      var data = {
          fname: this.fname,
          lname: this.lname,
          age: this.age
      }
      // http://localhost:3000/entry
      this.$http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', data, { emulateJSON: true })
      .then((resp) => {
          console.log(resp);
          return this.getAll();
       })
       .then(() => {
          this.isSaving = false;
          this.fname = null;
          this.lname = null;
          this.age = null;
       })
    },
    
    getAll() {
       // http://localhost:3000/entries
       this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
       .then((data) => {
           console.log(data);
           this.objects = data.body;
       })
    }
  },

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.5.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>
          Dashboard
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <form class="row" @submit.prevent="checkForm">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="fname" name="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="lname" name="lname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="environment">Age</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="age" name="age" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input href="#" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit" :disabled="isSaving">
        <span v-show='isSaving'>Saving...</span>
      </div>
    </form> 

    <div>&nbsp;</div>

    <!--<div class="row" v-if="debug">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div> -->

    <!-- Table Start -->

    <div class="row">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="item in objects" :key="item._id">
          <!-- item.fname -->
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <!-- item.lname -->
          <td>{{item.username}}</td>
          <!-- item.age -->
          <td>{{item.email}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Table END -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do it with VueJS only

Comment: @DineshAhuja this is vuejs way, and you already use `vue-resource` (ajax library for Vue) I see it in your index.html. And `checkFrom` is your Vue instance method.

Comment: it is not redirecting. But data is not updating

Comment: console.log('Saved!'); it is not coming too

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Form is submitting correctly now. But, data is not appearing into table

Comment: In this table field only {{item.fname}} , {{item.lname}}, {{item.age}} showing, but not the values

Comment: console.log(data); it is giving correct output. But data is not appearing into the table.

Comment: @DineshAhuja I think you missed something in your template, it works in example.

Comment: In my JSON id is like, "_id": "5b48a137c3b2a3454b853a3c" do you think that it is causing the problem ?

Comment: @DineshAhuja don't think so, looks like your table is not inside Vue root element, can you show your updated code?

Comment: Updated the HTML, please check

Comment: @DineshAhuja i just copied your js(old) and html form question and added `objects` array. See it shows table well https://jsfiddle.net/6y9ehw7k/

Comment: I think problem is that, template is loading faster than API call

Comment: if template loaded it uses `objects` array which is empty then request fetched data and just assign `objects` array, this is not related loading timing. Try create fiddle and reproduce issue, I dont know